# Accessing VisualSVN Server on port 81

Tags: svn, windows-server-2008-r2, visualsvn-server

I have a virtual machine with Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard on it, I installed TFS, IIS and VisualSVN Server and I can access IIS and TFS from other pc, but not VisualSVN Server.
Every application is bound to a port : TFS 8080, IIS 80, and VisualSVN Server 81.
When I put the URL of VisualSVN Server in a browser, it works when I'm on the virtual machine, but not from another pc.

What I've done :
- I added a rule in windows firewall so it can accept connections on the port 81 => Didn't work.
- I stopped the IIS, changed the VisualSVN Server to 80 => it works !

Answer (score 0):

Check the port forwarding options for the VM if there are any. According to the problem description and to the fact that it works on port 80, it seems that you missed some configuration step. I'd also try port 443 with HTTPS instead of plain HTTP on port 80. There is a chance that port 80 is blocked on VM's level by some reason.